# Why function receive extra argument

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

When I run an function with the code below:

```
elements = ["A", "B"]

for element <- elements, into: [] do
  struct(element, [])
end
```

Elixir raise this exception:

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Kernel.struct/3

The following arguments were given to Kernel.struct/3:

    # 1
    "A"

    # 2
    []

    # 3
    #Function<18.114860832/2 in Kernel.struct/2>

Attempted function clauses (showing 4 out of 4):

    defp struct(struct, [], _fun) when is_atom(struct)
    defp struct(struct, fields, fun) when is_atom(struct)
    defp struct(%_{} = struct, [], _fun)
    defp struct(%_{} = struct, fields, fun)
```

Why Elixir pass an function as third parameter to Kernel.struct function?

Comment: What version of Elixir are you running? I can't seem to find a definition for `struct/3`, only `struct/2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are seeing `Kernel.struct/3` is that `Kernel.struct/2` [calls](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.9/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L2112) a private [`Kernel.struct/3`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.9/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L2160) clause internally.

The reason for the error, that there is no matching function clause, is because the first argument `"A"` is not a struct or an atom. Please read the [documentation for `struct/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#struct/2):

> The `struct` argument may be an atom (which defines `defstruct`) or a `struct` itself.

You are passing a string, which is not a valid argument.